# Convert Audio call speaker to mic

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

i'm developing an app in which i'm making a video call using twilio. Now when i make a a video call it runs properly. But the voice of both parties is on speaker, i want to give user flexibility that it can either speak using speaker or mic, how can i do this using swift? I have searched for it, it shows me this function in this function speaker get enable and disable but don't convert to mic. How i can convert speaker voice to mic or mic to speaker?

```
 @IBAction func speakerBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if (self.localAudioTrack != nil) {
        //MARK:- Usage  for Enable
        self.setAudioOutputSpeaker(enabled: true)
    }
    else
    {
        //MARK:- Usage  for Disable
        self.setAudioOutputSpeaker(enabled: false)
    }
}
//MARK:- Manual Speaker Enagle and Disable
func setAudioOutputSpeaker(enabled: Bool)
{
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    var _: Error?
    try? session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
    try? session.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
    if enabled {
        try? session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
    } else {
        try? session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.none)
    }
    try? session.setActive(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly then you would like to provide a feature, where user can select the way for input of voice, **either Speaker or Microphone** then, that functionalities is not available in existing iOS Technologies.

There is no method to `overrideIutputAudioPort`, only you can `overrideOutputAudioPort` and send the incoming voice to Speaker or Microphone based on your choice.

> For now, if overrideOutputAudioPort is speaker then input is speaker and vice versa

You can also refer the most popular apps, like [WhatsApp](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997?mt=8), [Google Duo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-duo-simple-video-calling/id1096918571?mt=8), there doesn't exists such options.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have check on whatsapp, when i hit speaker button we can listen through microphone, how this can be done here? I want to give this authority to user to either talk on speaker or microphone. @Bhavin Kansagara

Comment: NO, as far as I know, that is not possible in iOS Technologies. However the same is available in Android. When the phone is on speaker, you can listen on speaker, as well as on connected earphone in Android WhatsApp. But for iOS WhatsApp, it stops playing audio on Earphone when you press the Speaker button. On which iOS Device have you tested?

Comment: I'm testing on iphone 7plus. Its working fine i have made call through whatsapp and during call i click on speaker option i hear sound on speaker and when again click on it than i hear it through microphone. @Bhavin Kansagara

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 - use below code snippet

// Change the audio route after connecting to a Room.

func moveToMic() {

```
    audioDevice.block = {
        DefaultAudioDevice.DefaultAVAudioSessionConfigurationBlock()
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setMode(.voiceChat)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    audioDevice.block();

}
```